# How to Integrate Prism, Unity, and Enterprise Library

Tags: prism, unity-container, enterprise-library, prism-4

I'm building a WPF application. I'm using Prism 4, and Unity. I want to add two Enterprise Library 5 blocks to the application, Logging and Exception Handling. I have a singleton LoggerFacadeCustom.cs in my Infrastructure class that supports the ILoggerFacade and I've created it in my bootstrapper, and it is generating log files. It "news" up a unity container in its constructor (second code block)

Where do I add the container.resolve for ExceptionManager? How do I connect the Exception handling block to ILoggerFacade in my bootstrapper? How do I get all the exceptions to come out in the same log?  Here is my existing bootstrapper.cs

```cs
  public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper {

     protected override ILoggerFacade CreateLogger() {
        return LoggerFacadeCustom.Instance;
     }

     protected override DependencyObject CreateShell() {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
     }

     protected override void InitializeShell() {
        base.InitializeShell();

        App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();

     //Other shell stuff...

     }

     protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog() {

        var catalog = new ModuleCatalog();

        //These primary modules must register their own services as if they were acting independantly
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(XmlCommentMergeModule));

        //These support modules require at least one primary module above to be added first
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(ToolboxHeaderModule));
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(ToolboxFooterModule));
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(ToolboxStartModule));
        return catalog;
     }
  }
```

LoggerFacadeCustom:

```cs
  public class LoggerFacadeCustom : ILoggerFacade {

     private static readonly LoggerFacadeCustom _instance = new LoggerFacadeCustom();
     public static LoggerFacadeCustom Instance { get { return _instance; } }

     private LoggerFacadeCustom() {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.AddNewExtension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();

        _logWriter = container.Resolve<LogWriter>();
     }

     private readonly LogWriter _logWriter;


     public void Write(string message) { Write(message, null); }

           public void Write(string message, string category, int priority) {
     _logWriter.Write(message, category, priority);
  }

           public void Write(string message, Dictionary<string, object> properties) {
     _logWriter.Write(message, LiteralString.LogCategoryProcess, properties);
  }


     #region ILoggerFacade Members

     public void Log(string message, Category category, Priority priority) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
     }

     #endregion
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrapper is the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) of your application. You should register all dependencies there. And only there. You should never reference the container directly outside the composition root.

If your classes have a dependency you should inject that dependency using a pattern like [constructor injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Don't use static classes. Static kills dependency injection and testability and it hides dependencies to a point where everything is referenced from everywhere.

Make your logger facade a constructor parameter. You can do the same with the error handling block.

Don't use the container as a ServiceLocator. That is considered an [anti-pattern in modern software architecture](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Comment: Microsoft's Prism book suggests using the container in each module for unity. Explain to me how a module can register interfaces without using the container? However, you should get that container using DI, not creating it yourself

Comment: @Alan You can outsource that configuration into special classes that derive from `UnityContainerExtension` and bundle the config for a module. Let your bootstrapper search for those classes and add them to your single container instance. Or you can inject a container instance into the module and do the config there. I think that is a valid short cut too.

Comment: For me, each module has an IModule class and injects the container through the constructor. Then the Initialize registers the types and resolves any services that the Module owns.